# recursive backtracker algorithm - pseudo code for function that calls itself

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I was looking for simple recursive algorithms for randomly generating a maze for a game and I came across an algorithm called [recursive backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Recursive_backtracker). Since my maze consists of 15 by 15 squares where each cell is either an empty space or a wall, I modified the algorithm slightly:

- Fill the grid with walls
- Pick a random direction
- If the cell in that direction is a wall and doesn't have two empty neighbours, clear that cell
- else pick another random direction
- If there are no available neighbours remaining, backtrack to the previous cell and try again

My project requires me to use recursive algorithms (I'm using python). This means that I need to use a function that calls itself. Can anyone suggest to me some python/psuedo code that fulfills the above criteria using a function that calls itself?

Example of a recursive algorithm:

```
def factorial(number):
    if number <= 1: #base case
        return 1
    else:
        return number * factorial(number-1)
```

Comment: the example algorithm doesn't really exhibit how to control the "backtracking" tho

Comment: how are you representing the 15x15 squares? how is a wall represented?

Comment: @naomik Ignore the example, it was simply an example of a function that calls itself for people who needed more clarification on what I meant. The grid is a 17x17 2d array, however the outside walls make up the border, making the actual maze 15x15. To clarify I was only looking for basic/simple pseudo code that expands on the Wikipedia example in the way that I want it to (each cell is either a wall or empty, a wall is represented by 1, empty space by 0)